# How do I create this Table with html

Tags: html

I need to create this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G7Zr.png) with html, but I don't understand yet how to separate the different rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **colspan**
> This attribute contains a non-negative integer value that indicates for how many columns the cell extends. Its default value is 1. Values higher than 1000 will be considered as incorrect and will be set to the default value (1)

> **rowspan**
> This attribute contains a non-negative integer value that indicates for how many rows the cell extends. Its default value is 1; if its value is set to 0, it extends until the end of the table section (, , , even if implicitly defined), that the cell belongs to. Values higher than 65534 are clipped down to 65534.

[colspan & rowspan documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan)

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
}

td,
th {
    padding: 10px;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.left {
    text-align: left;
}

table,
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.max {
    width: 60%;
}

.min {
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="left">Project</th>
        <td colspan="4">Marketplace 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="left">Group</th>
        <td colspan="4">Group 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="5" class="left">Members</th>
        <th class="max">Name</th>
        <th class="min">Role</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 1</td>
        <td>Scrum Master</td>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 2</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 3</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 4</td>
        <td>Developer / Devops</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me with this, it's the same table but in Spanish:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Proyecto</th>
      <td colspan="2">Marketplace 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Grupo</th>
      <td colspan="2">Grupo 17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <tr>
         <th rowspan="5">Integrantes</th>
         <th>Nombre</th>
         <th>Rol</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Carlos Figueredo Triana</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Carlos Figueredo Triana</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Carlos Figueredo Triana</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Carlos Figueredo Triana</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```